# how to stop movement if the object hits the boundary in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

display_width = 800
display_height = 600
FPS = 20

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("The Space Jumpers")

img = pygame.image.load('starship2.png')
spritesize = 50
boundlimit = 200

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

def gameLoop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    lead_x = display_width / 2
    lead_y = display_height / 2
    xchange = 0
    ychange = 0

    randBlockX = random.randrange(0,boundlimit+1)
    randBlockY = random.randrange(0,575)

    while not gameExit:
        gameDisplay.blit(img, [lead_x,lead_y])
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    xchange = -spritesize / 2
                    ychange = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    xchange = spritesize / 2
                    ychange = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    ychange = -spritesize / 2
                    xchange = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    ychange = spritesize / 2
                    xchange = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    xchange = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    ychange = 0











        lead_x += xchange
        lead_y += ychange 

        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,red, [randBlockX, randBlockY, 600, 25])

        if (lead_x+spritesize < randBlockX and randBlockY<lead_y<randBlockY+25) :
            randBlockX = random.randrange(0,boundlimit+1)
            randBlockY = random.randrange(0,575)
        elif (lead_x+spritesize < randBlockX and randBlockY<lead_y<randBlockY+25 ):
            randBlockX = random.randrange(0,boundlimit+1)
            randBlockY = random.randrange(0,575)
        elif (lead_x > randBlockX+600 and randBlockY<lead_y<randBlockY+25):
            randBlockX = random.randrange(0,boundlimit+1)
            randBlockY = random.randrange(0,575)
        elif (lead_x > randBlockX+600 and randBlockY<lead_y<randBlockY+25):
            randBlockX = random.randrange(0,boundlimit+1)
            randBlockY = random.randrange(0,575)






        clock.tick(FPS)   


    pygame.quit()
    quit()

gameLoop()
```

This is my current code and in this code when the object(sprite) hits the boundary, it keeps on moving but what I want to do is, I want to stop the movement of the object when it hits the boundary, for example when the object hits the left boundary it shouldnt move left anymore. You kind of get the idea, its a simple game

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Look up questions here about `pygame` and collision detection.

Comment: @martineau thank you so much but when I do that all the movements are nullified, i m only able to move up and down

Comment: Well...then you must be doing it wrong. Update your question and include the modified code. Also, what are the dimension of the `starship2.png` image?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two variables (`lead_x`, `lead_y`) to store the position of the object, use a [`Rect`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). It's as simple as

```
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
gameDisplay_rect = gameDisplay.get_rect()

img = pygame.image.load('starship2.png')
img_rect = img.get_rect(center=gameDisplay_rect.center)
```

To draw you object, simply do:

```
gameDisplay.blit(img, img_rect)
```

Now, to move your object, instead of

```
 lead_x += xchange
 lead_y += ychange
```

you can do

```
 img_rect.move_ip(lead_x, lead_y)
 img_rect.clamp_ip(gameDisplay_rect)
```

[`clamp_ip`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip) will then prevent your object from leaving the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:
try changing your if statement(if pygame.key == pygame.K_LEFT:) to(if pygame.key == pygame.K_LEFT and x > 0:)

i have been struggling with the same thing for a school project and have gotten it so that it stops the sprite if you touch the border, but if you spam that button you can get through. I currently have an if statement saying(If x < 0: x_change = 0), but i have not tried the one i suggested. i hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

[sloth's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31825557/7311767) is for sure better in many ways, but if you still want to keep your old `lead_x`, `lead_y` structure you could just add a separate statements outside of the event loop:

```
if lead_x <= 0:
    lead_x += 10 # just use any small distance to push you back to place every frame
elif lead_x >= display_width:
    lead_x -= 10
```

and so on for every direction.